# Why does typecasting an object not change its address? Where is information about the object's type stored?

Tags: c++, casting

I just tested this out using qobject_cast (but I imagine it'd be the same for any other sort of type cast), and apparently casting an object to a different type does not change its address. This makes me think that information about the type of an object is stored elsewhere...is that correct?

I'm still new to C++, so if this makes no sense at all feel free to tell me that as well. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No. In general, informatiin about object type is not stored anywhere. There are exceptions to this but I do recommend to ignore this fact for now. As a new C++ prorammer, you should avoid casts like the plague.

Comment: As a general rule, if you discover that some *code* doesn't work like you think it should, and you want to ask about it here, you should post a [mcve]. Prefer a code example that can be tried to a general abstract formulation of your question.

Comment: Just to note that `qobject_cast` is specific to `Qt` and not part of `C++`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does typecasting an object not change its address?

Because typecasting has absolutely zero effect on the source object<sup>1</sup>. Type casting always produces a new object (of possibly different type) or a reference. Furthermore, there is no operation that could change the address of any object. An object is stored in one address throughout its entire lifetime.

If the result of a type cast is a reference, then that reference may refer to another object in different address, in particular when converting to a reference to a type in same inheritance hierarchy.

<sup>1</sup> Technically, a converting constructor or a conversion operator *could* modify the source object, but that would be horribly non-conventional.

> Where is information about the object's type stored?

Type information is "stored" by the compiler while it is compiling the program. In *general*, the information does not need to be stored by the program itself.

In *particular* case of polymorphic types, some information about the type of an object is stored in the memory of the program to support `dynamic_cast` and dynamic `typeid`. It is stored in whatever place the language implementation has chosen appropriate.

> I just tested this out using qobject_cast

There is no such thing as `qobject_cast` in C++. Perhaps you are using some library.

Comment: Thank you for the response! You mentioned that type casting always creates a new object, but that's exactly what I tested and found not to be a case. I used `cout` to see an object's address, type casted it to a different type and assigned that to a variable, then printed the address of that variable (in that order) and the same number (same address) was printed both times, which shows that the object was unchanged...I think? I am misunderstanding something? I'll copy paste my actual code here ASAP

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, typecasting actually does change the apparent address of the source object. The original source object's address doesn't change, but the address of "that same object" (not a newly-constructed converted object) may be different if an object, reference, or pointer to a derived class is cast via `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` to a reference or pointer to a base class, when the derived class inherits the base class in a multiple-inheritance hierarchy and the base classes either contain data or are polymorphic (or both). The "different address" is actually the address within the source object where the base class portion of the overall derived class resides.